# How do soft hyphens obfuscate URLs?

Tags: url, url-routing, hyphenation, soft-hyphen

I just got a piece of spam with the hyperlink obscured with soft hyphens. Since I don't actually want to click on the link, how do the soft hyphens create the URL obfuscation?

For example, how would I use soft hyphens to obfuscate http://www.google.com/ ?

Comment: Can't you watch the html or watch the raw message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an entire page of Symantec about it: http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/soft-hyphen-new-url-obfuscation-technique but I wasn't able to test it because Chrome and IE 9.0 show them. The trick is

```
&shy;
```

Now look at this:

```
http://www.my&shy;site.com;
```

In the DNS it is www.my(soft hypens)site.com, but to the user it's http://www.my­site.com (look at the source of this responce if you can using the `edit` link)

Comment: ok, got it. soft hyphens can be in the source HTML but do not appear at all in the rendered page. so text strings on a watchlist (mysite.com, as in your example) are written as my&shy;site.com in the HTML and therefore bypass the filters.

Comment: @henryyun Yes, something like this.